# How to start eclipse with my own splash screen

Tags: eclipse, splash-screen

I want to start an fully functional eclipse workbench with my own plugins and my own splash screen.

How can I achieve this ?

I know how to start eclipse with my plugins but how can I put my own splash into the start process of eclipse ?

Comment: Look at the help for [Splash Handlers](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_splashHandlers.html) - assuming this is a 3.x style RCP

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly involved topic, really too detailed for a complete answer here in SO. But there are several tutorials and guides that can help. I'd start with this one: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseProductDeployment/article.html

The gist is that you need to define a *Product* (Eclipse RCP terminology) where you configure many aspects of branding, including splash screen.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I created my own product but when I try to build my executable under windows I get the following error:

 An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
 session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
 Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.platform,4.3.2.v20140221-1700.

Comment: That sounds like a different question/problem, requiring troubleshooting and lots more details.